# Dejar un select sin optiones

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente `select` donde selecciono un tipo de madera y este tiene sub productos de esta, pero en ocaciones la madera no tiene sub producto asi que lo esconde el select del subproducto. Pero al momento de rescatar los datos y enviarlo mediantes AJAX a la base de datos me envia el sub producto siendo que el `select` esta escondido

Hay alguna forma de dejar el valor de este select subproducto null?

```js
$("#clasificacion").change(function() {

    var valor = $(this).val(); // Capturamos el valor del select
    var texto = $(this).find('option:selected').text(); // Capturamos el texto del option seleccionado


    switch (texto) {
        case 'Madera1':
            $("#divhidden").first().show("fast", function() {});
            var newOptions = {
                "Madera1.1": "Madera1.1",
                "Madera1.2": "Madera1.2"
            };

            var $el = $('#subclasificacion');
            $el.html(' ');
            $.each(newOptions, function(key, value) {
                $el.append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value", value).text(key));
            });
           
            break;
        case 'Madera2':
            $("#divhidden").hide(100);
        
            break;
    
        case 'Madera3':
           $("#divhidden").first().show("fast", function() {});
            var newOptions = {
                "Madera3.1": "Madera3.1",
                "Madera3.2": "Madera3.2"
            };

            var $el = $('#subclasificacion');
            $el.html(' ');
            $.each(newOptions, function(key, value) {
                $el.append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value", value).text(key));
            });
            break;
      
      
   
    }

});
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <div class="col-sm-3">
             <small>Clasificacion Producto</small>
        <select class="form-group browser-default custom-select" id="clasificacion">
           <option selected disabled>.::Clasificacion::.</option>
           <option value="Madera1">Madera1</option>
           <option value="Madera2">Madera2</option>
           <option value="Madera3">Madera3</option>
              
                        </select>
                      </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3" id="divhidden">
                            <label>Sub Clasificacion Producto</label>
          <select class="form-group browser-default custom-select" id="subclasificacion">
               
                                <option value="Madera1.1">Madera1.1</option>
                                <option value="Madera1.1">Madera1.2</option>

                            </select>
                        </div>
```

Espero haberme explicado bien. Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una alternativa, y que considero que responde a una buena práctica, sobre todo cuando refrescas la información con ajax, es que para todos los listados agregues una opción por defecto.
Por ejemplo:

```
var newOptions = {
            "-1":"Seleccione..",
            "Madera1.1": "Madera1.1",
            "Madera1.2": "Madera1.2"
        };
```

Lo que generará algo como:

```
<option value="-1">Seleccione...</option>
```

Asegúrate de que cada vez que selecciones un listado padre, el listado hijo apunte a dicha opción por defecto.

También sería bueno que trabajes con un valor que para tí represente el nulo, (como el -1 en mi ejemplo) y no que mandes null directamente, porque al manejar un valos cuatificable, es más sencillo operar sobre él.

El problema actual es que simplemente ocultas el segundo combobox cuando escoges "madera 2", pero sigue manteniendo los valores del último combobox principal seleccionado. Es por eso que te servirá agregar esa opción por defecto.

Quedaría algo así.

```
case 'Madera2':
        $("#divhidden").first().show("fast", function() {});
        var newOptions = {
            "-1": "Esto jamás se verá"
        };

        var $el = $('#subclasificacion');
        $el.html(' ');
        $.each(newOptions, function(key, value) {
            $el.append($("<option></option>")
                .attr("value", value).text(key));
        });

        $("#divhidden").hide(100);

        break;
```

En este caso, se creará una sublista y por defecto asumirá el valor -1 (la ocultará tal y como lo haces hasta aquí), que ya podrías capturar para continuar con tu lógica de negocios.

Espero aportar